# TypeScript union type cannot be used as an array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

This is as far as I was able to reduce the problem to:

```
interface Word {
    value: string | string[];
}

const w: Word = {
    value: [] as string[] 
    // also tried: 
    // value: []
    // value: ['test']
}

w.value.push('')
```

The last line errors in my IDE because *"push" does not exist for the type "string | string[]" (ts2339)*. It also wouldn't compile!

Is it a bug? Is it feature? How to help this?

Comment: I'd actually just make this always `string[]` to avoid things like this.

Comment: It's not a bug, but "how to help this" depends on your use case.  By annotating `w` as being of type `Word`, the compiler gives `w` that type.  Even though you initialize `w.value` to `string[]`, the compiler does not narrow `w` to `{value: string[]}` upon assignment.   See [ms/TS#33205](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33205). Personally I'd just not annotate `w` at all and let the compiler infer it as `{value: string[]}` to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[] as string[]` doesn't really do much in your code, since it's already clear from the usage that this array would be a string array, and you then assign the object to a `Word`. You've defined `Word` so that value can be either a string or a string array, and while you might have started off with an array, the type you defined says you might change it to a string on a different line of code. Since the value might not be an array, typescript won't let you push to it unless you first verify that it's an array.

For example:

```
if (Array.isArray(w.value)) {
  w.value.push('');
} else {
  w.value = [w.value, ''];
}
```

If you want `w` to be a narrower type, one that's similar to `Word` but guarantees that the value is always an array, then do this:

```
const w: Word & { value: string[] } = {
 value: []
}
```